# GCP alert if Docker container exits

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-swarm, google-cloud-monitoring

We are using Google Cloud Platform and its service Compute Engine. We have Docker installed on one of our VM instances (which is part of Compute Engine). Can we set up an alert in GCP Monitoring to be triggered when a container exits?

Comment: When a container exist where?

Comment: On the VM that is part of Compute Engine.

Comment: You would have to write a bunch of custom code.

Comment: if this works https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-gcplogs-driver, then use log based metrics to create an alert to notify you. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics

Comment: Thanks @danyL  I created a POC based on this below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You have to configure docker with Cloud logging driver, create a log based metric and an alerting policy on that metric.

***Solution:***

**Configure docker with cloud logging driver.**

- SSH to your instance.
- Run this command as root: `dockerd --log-driver=gcplogs`. This will forward your docker logs to Google Cloud Logging.
- If running a container-optimized OS then follow these steps:

  `echo '{"log-driver":"gcplogs"}' | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json`

  `sudo systemctl restart docker`
- Try starting and exiting a container.

These are the logs generated whenever we exit a container. Keep in mind the **two exit** messages
[image: logs generated]

**Create a log based metric**

- Go to Logging -> Select Log-based Metrics.
- Click on Create Metric.
- Metric Type: Counter. In Details, enter a Log Metric name (e.g. mysite-container-exited)
- Under Filter Selection -> Build filter, copy the following code

  `resource.type="gce_instance"`

  `log_name="projects/myproject-12345/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver"` replace ***myproject-12345*** with your project name.

  `jsonPayload.container.name="/mysite"` change ***mysite*** to your container name.

  `jsonPayload.message=~"exit$"` This is regex that matches ***exit*** as the last word in a line.

It should look something like this.
[image]

**Create an alerting policy**

- Go to Monitoring -> Select Alerting.
- Click on Create Policy.
- Click on Select a Metric and search for your metric name (e.g. mysite-container-exited).
- Select your metric and click on Apply.
  [image]
- Set Rolling window to **2 min** and Rolling window function to **count**. Click Next.
  [image]
- Set Alert Trigger to **Any time series violates**, Threshold postion to **Above threshold** and Threshold value to **1**. Click Next.
  [image]
- Select a notification Channel to send alerts to. If none exists then click on Manage Notification Channels and create one.
- Easiest one would be to add an email for notification channel.
- After creating go back, click on Refresh icon in Notification Channels and select it. Click ok.
- Click on Save Policy.

As we have seen that **two exit** commands are issued **per container** to the logs whenever we exit a container, thats's why the threshold is set to above **1**.

You can monitor more containers by creating a new metric and changing the value of `jsonPayload.container.name="/mysite"` to your container name.

Now try to start and stop the container. You will receive an alert on email in 2-3 minutes.
[image]